# How to get the number of elements in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, schematron

I have started with Schematron and XPath. In Schematron document I  to provide context for validating m business rule so I am providing section/body/p. As I have provided p tag in context then How can I query to count  total no of p tags? This is the XML file

```
  <section>
    <body>
        <p>
            <t>Document Body</t>
        </p>
        <p>
            <t>Document Body</t>
        </p>
        <p>
            <t>Document Body</t>
        </p>
    </body>
</section>
```

And this is how I am querying

```
 <sch:pattern name="ELEMENT_LIMIT">
    <sch:rule context="section/body/p" >
        <sch:assert test="count(.//following-sibling::p) &lt;=2">more than 1 sibling</sch:assert>
    </sch:rule> 
 </sch:pattern>
```

but this is not working.

Comment: Why `&lt;=2` and not `&gt;=2`?

Comment: I'm finding this to be a strange approach and maybe there's missing context ... but why wouldn't you choose `context="section/body"` and then make your XPath expression into `count(./p) &gt;=2` (or whatever you want). `following-sibling::p` is only counting siblings that are `<p>` elements, which means that if there's a `<div>` tag in the middle, it'll mess up the counting. Unless that's what you actually want ...

Comment: Schematron implementation (probatron) returns the context where the assertion fails that's why I am using section/body/p to get the XPath of actual p tag. I want only 2 p tags under body tag of more than 2 then it should return XPath of extra p tag

Answer (score 0):

This reports, if a `<p>` element has less than 2 following-sibling `<p>` elements.

```
<sch:pattern id="too-many-following-siblings">
    <sch:rule context="p">
        <sch:report test="count(following-sibling::p) lt 2">
            Less than 2 following-sibling &lt;p&gt; elements.
        </sch:report>
    </sch:rule>
</sch:pattern>
```